# How can I discover what "No AirPrint printers found" means?

Tags: printing, airprint

I've had generally good experience with the ippserver at https://github.com/istopwg/ippsample on Windows. I've spooled pdf files "printed" from an iPad. I don't rely on Bonjour printer discovery. I'm using iOS Configuration Profiles.

Sometimes I get "No AirPrint printers found". I know from the logging that the iPad has interacted with ippserver so it has found the printer. How can I find out what lies behind this bland error message? Are there system logs that will contain the details of precisely what has gone wrong?

Comment: How can you get around bonjour discovery with configuration profiles?

Comment: @IPPNerd If you send a configuration profile to an iOS device that has an AirPrint payload and when the user tries to print to the printer in the payload is available it will be presented as an option even if it is not discoverable by Bonjour. So, the printer can be on the internet. Obviously, some random printer on the internet is not going to be Bonjour discoverable. I knew nothing about these profiles and was steered towards them by Micheal Sweet when I asked him why, having ported ippserver to iOS, the iPad did not discover the ippserver running on itself.

Comment: @IPPNerd see https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12